# Run specified javascript after page loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Here is the structure of my project:

```
Project:
    Default.aspx
    Reports.aspx
    Scripts:
           myscript.js
```

I have a situation, when I'm navigating from Reports.aspx page to Default.aspx page, which is loading in new tab, and in this situation, only in this situation I want to run myscript.js at Default.aspx page.

How can I do this?

Comment: For the most part, it's difficult to detect tabs/windows due to the stateless nature of the web.

Comment: i go to Default.asp from Reports.aspx by <a href ... target="_blank">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a querystring parameter when you go to the default page.

```
Response.Redirect("page2.aspx?insertParameterHere=true",true)
```

In your default page you can then check if that parameter exists.

```
Request.QueryString("insertParameterHere")
```